# Flutter function with named and optional parameters

Tags: function, flutter, dart, parameters, optional-parameters

I have a function that should have three `required` and in best case `named` parameters. The last one ("`finished`") should be `optional`. I tried it like this:

```
static void showOverlay(BuildContext context, String text, bool successfull,
  [VoidCallback? finished]) {}
```

but Flutter is complaining:

> Avoid positional boolean parameters

The weird thing is that it is only complaining about the `bool successfull`. What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: @lrsvmb but right now the params are not named

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Named parameters are optional by default. So in your case it would be:

```
static void showOverlay({BuildContext context, String text, bool successfull, VoidCallback? finished}) {}
```

Notice the {} in the constructor, this makes your parameters named and optional. By using @required in front of your declaration, you can differentiate between required and not required.

Comment: For future reference, if you have enabled null-safety: `@required` is now just `required`

Answer (score 3):

you can use it like this using positional parameters

```
 void showOverlay(BuildContext context, String text, bool successful, [VoidCallback finished]) {}
```

or like this using named parameters

```
void showOverlay({@required BuildContext context, @required String text, @required bool successful, VoidCallback finished}) {}
```

and dart is complaining becuase named parameters is best practice as mentioned in dart docs

**Positional boolean parameters are a bad practice because they are very ambiguous. Using named boolean parameters is much more readable because it inherently describes what the boolean value represents.**

**BAD:**

```
Task(true);
Task(false);
ListBox(false, true, true);
Button(false);
```

**GOOD:**

```
Task.oneShot();
Task.repeating();
ListBox(scroll: true, showScrollbars: true);
Button(ButtonState.enabled);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Named parameters are optional unless they’re specifically marked as required](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters).
Below, all four of your parameters are named. Three are `required` while one of them is optional.

```
static void showOverlay({required BuildContext context, required String text, 
  required bool successfull, VoidCallback? finished}) {}
```